# Bounds in wilcoxon equivalence test

Tags: equivalence, pairwise.wilcox.test

I conducted an equivalence test for variables that are not normally distributed, by the `wilcox_TOST` function (from TOSTER package in R) for paired samples.
here is my code:

`wilcox_TOST(x, y, hypothesis = "EQU",  paired = TRUE, eqb=0.3, ses = "rb", alpha = 0.05)`

Regarding the bounds (0.3 and -0.3) - What are their values? Effect size? Raw values?
I can't find that in the manual.
How can I know how much it is in terms of effect size (rank biserial correlation), or alternatively in Z values?